# Display Related List from Custom Object on Case Layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout

I would like to display a related list from a custom object on my Case record. Please reference the information below:

- Case Object: Contains a lookup field (Listing__c)
- Listing Object: Master in a master-detail relationship with an object called Booking Rule(BookingRule__c)
- Booking Rule Record: Due to the master-detial relationship, every Booking Rule record is associated to a Listing

Big Idea: The Case object and Booking Rule object are unrelated. However, they are somewhat related due to the Listing lookup field on the Case record. I would like to display the Booking Rules related list from my custom object (Listing__c) page layout on my Case page layout.

I hear a visualforce page will do the job. However, I'm unsure where to start, what APEX code to use and how to bring it all together.

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help me out!

Comment: So you want to show all Booking Rules related to Listings related to Cases, but on the Case object?

Comment: The Listing lookup field lives on the Case Record. I want to show all Booking Rules related to that Listing record as a section on the Case page layout. Basically, there will be a section, on the Case page layout, of all Booking Rules  related to the Listing within the Case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<apex:relatedList>` tag. It's dead simple.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!Cae.Listing__c}" list="BookingRules__r" />
</apex:page>
```

You can run this script to get the verbatim `list` name:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Listing__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == BookingRule__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Comment: I created the VF page, added the VF page to the layout and I received the following error: "Content cannot be displayed: 'BookingRules__r' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Listing". I don't understand, because when I look at the Schema Builder the Listing (Listing__c) object has a master-detail relationship with Booking Rule. @AdrianLarson

Comment: Hence why I included the second script. Did you run it? Just paste into Execute Anonymous.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm an Admin, my apologies. However, when running the script will it affect any current code, code blocks, API connections or anything else in the system?

Comment: Nope. It won't affect anything as you are running that in "Execute Anonymous Window"

Comment: No,  Execute Anonymous will not affect your code base. It's throwaway code you can use for one off processing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ok. Last question: if this is one off processing, how will the VF page work on new Cases that are created down the road?

Comment: The one off part is the script you use to get the relationship name. Not the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do. Here is my approach to display booking related list in case page layout.
1. Create a lookup relationship in booking to case object.
2. create a trigger on booking object. Creation of every booking tag case record from using listing object.
3. Then add booking related list in case page layout.

2nd approach VF page.
Vf page

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="BookingExtenion">
    <apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!bookingList}" var="book">
        <apex:column value="{!book.name}" />
    </apex:pageblockTable>  
    </apex:pageblock>  
</apex:page>
```

and controller

```
public with sharing class BookingExtenion {
    public List<booking> bookingList {get;set;}
    public Case caseRecord {get;set;}
    public BookingExtenion(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        caseRecord  = (Case)controller.getRecord();
        Map<ID, Listing> listingMap = new Map<ID, booking>([SELECT Id, LastName FROM Listing where case__c=caseRecord.id]);
        bookingList = [select id,name from booking where listing__c in :listingMap.keySet()]
    }
}
```

then add this vf page in case page layout

Comment: Hey Shravan, I considered that too! but I do not want to add another lookup field to the Booking object. So, I believe the VF methodology is the next best step. I simply need to know how to write the controller and VF page. Thanks.

Comment: @LarryCaper.modified answer with vf page approach

Comment: Almost! thanks for the attempt, but I think there may be an error related to how the fields and/or objects are written. The Booking Rule (BookingRule__c) object is a child to the master Listing custom object (Listing__c). The Case record has a Listing Lookup field (Listing__c).

Comment: @LarryCaper Shravan's solution is the easiest and best approach. That should be a start for you. If that solve your problem, please explain the issue more.

Comment: @SFDC_BigDog I completely agree, but I can't add another lookup field due to a potential coding issue. I was specifically asked to do this via VF and Controller.

Comment: @LarryCaper Where exactly you are worried about adding an extra field. I mean as you have explained, there is already a lookup field to Listing__c on Case. So in this code we are not adding any extra field. We are just creating a section to get the bookingrule__c items for that related listing__C

Comment: @SFDC_BigDog After pasting the code, I received numerous errors: appending "__c", missing semi-colon, "Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: booking at line 2 column 17" and "No such column 'case__c' on entity 'Listing__c'".